# What is this piece of assembly code into C?

Tags: assembly, x86, conditional-statements, att

**ATT syntax.**

I'm trying to understand what the following piece of assembly code does:

```
movl  8(%ebp), %edx
movl  $0, %eax
testl %edx, %edx
je    .L7
.L10:
xorl  %edx, %eax
shrl  %edx
jne   .L10
.L7:
andl  $1, %eax
```

It's supposed to be the body of a function with one parameter: unsigned x. I know that this is a **do-while loop** but how can I completely convert it to C code?

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working? This isn't a code translation service; you need to make some effort to figure things out yourself, and then ask specific questions here if you run into problems.

Comment: This is practice problem I can't figure out. I'll ask more specific questions from here on out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned int function(unsigned int x)
{
  unsigned int a = 0;

  while (x != 0)
  {
    a = a ^ x;
    x = x >> 1;
  }

  a = a & 1;

  return a;
}
```

Comment: Where does the xor come into play? What does it do?

Comment: It basically do nothing. x xor 0 = x. I don't think this code makes any sense.

Comment: @user1920281 you could replace your function with `return 0;` which will behave the same. The `eax` register is modified by the xor and carried to the next iteration, this code actually does something.

Comment: @lbonn 
if the asm means edx = edx ^ eax how can it carry over to eax?
I don't know much about asm just want to learn.

Comment: @user1920281 this sample uses the AT&T syntax so the xor operation must be read `eax = eax ^ edx`. If you used the Intel syntax before, this can indeed be confusing because in AT&T, the result operand is on the right and not on the left as it is with Intel.

Comment: @lbonn Thanks for pointing it out my confusion. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
void or unsigned some_function(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned edx = x;
  unsigned eax = 0;
  if (edx == 0)
    goto L7;
L10:
  eax ^= edx;
  if ((edx >>= 1) != 0)
    goto L10;
L7:
  eax &= 1;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `shrl %edx` is not incomplete. If there is no shift count, it is implied to be 1, so the C code would be `edx >>= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that `eax` is the return register in x86 (even though this snippet does not contain the `ret` instruction).
Here, the function returns true if the first bit of `eax` is 1.

This algorithm xor all bits of the input and return the resulting bit.

It can be summarized in a short high-level sentence: it returns 1 if the numbers of 1 bits of the input is odd and 0 if it's even (you need to think a little about it to see it, I can explain more thoroughly if you need more details).